# SharedPreferences for multiple activities using an extend class

Tags: java, android, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have an application with three activities. Here is my Activity lifecycle: Activity1 -> Activity2 -> Activity3. All my activities are use 'exactly' the same preferences.
So i created an extend class which is used from all of my activities.
Example

```
public class myPreferences extends Activity{

protected string PlayerName;
protected float maxPlayerHealth;
protected float minPlayerHealth;
// there are about 15 variables

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("general_settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

PlayerName = prefs.getString("PlayerName", null);

maxPlayerHealth = prefs.getFloat("PlayerName", 0.0f);

minPlayerHealth = prefs.getFloat("PlayerName", 0.0f);

//etc for rest of my preferences
}
```

Here an example from each of my activities.

```
public class Activity1 extends myPreferences{ 
}
public class Activity2 extends myPreferences{ 
}
public class Activity3 extends myPreferences{ 
}
```

So my question is, if it is better to use static variables inside my class, and running sharedPreferences only once in my application. Example i will check if player name is null.

```
public class myPreferences extends Activity{

protected static string PlayerName;
protected static float maxPlayerHealth;
protected static float minPlayerHealth;
// there are about 15 variables

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

  if(PlayerName ==null)
  {
      SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("general_settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

      PlayerName = prefs.getString("PlayerName", null);

      maxPlayerHealth = prefs.getFloat("PlayerName", 0.0f);

      minPlayerHealth = prefs.getFloat("PlayerName", 0.0f);

      //etc for rest of my preferences
   }
}
```

Which of two methods are better? 
1) What about memory usage? Static variables will use more memory? Is it risky for memory leaks?
2) Which of two methods will have better performance? I think if i dont read always my preferences it will be slightly better.
3) Should i use private signature instead of protected or it doesn't matter?
4) If all my activities are open in stack at the same time, variables will be recreated 3 times? One for each activity which extends the class myPreferences?

Comment: It doesn't matter - for what it's worth I wouldn't put this in a base `Activity`, but would instead create my own `PlayerSettings` class that kept all of this internal, and only exposed accessors for `name()`, `maxHealth()` and `minHealth()`, but it's up to you. If you go with this approach, then I'd advice against making the values `static` as they'd be globally modifiable.

Comment: I am open for alternative solutions. Could you write an example?

Comment: Any example with your method?

Comment: I think what I'm describing is pretty straightforward, but fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of things to cover but I will try my best:

> What about memory usage?

In Java, when we only declare a variable of a class type, only a reference is created (memory is not allocated for the object). To allocate memory to an object, we must use new(). When you create a Static variable Stack Memory in Java is used. It contains primitive values that are specific to a method and references to objects that are in a heap, referred from the method. Access to this memory is in the Last-In-First-Out (LIFO) order. What it basically means is as soon as you create a static variable a piece of memory is allocated to it and this memory exists until your app is closed.

> Static variables will use more memory? Is it risky for memory leaks?

More memory? NO! But it will have a piece of memory basically assigned to it until the app is closed. `Is it risky for memory leaks?`- Yes, it could be as it might create a circular dependency which might not let your object type to be destroyed, I could be wrong but it won't happen in your case.

> Which of the two methods will have better performance? I think if I don't read always my preferences it will be slightly better.

In my knowledge static might have better performance as you will be carrying it in a variable and not have to get it from a bundle every time.

> Should I use a private signature instead of protected or it doesn't matter

A derived class doesn't inherit access to private data members. However, it does inherit a full parent object, which contains any private members which that class declares. So you can decide as per your use case.

> If all my activities are open in a stack at the same time, variables will be recreated 3 times? One for each activity which extends the class myPreferences?

If the item is static it will be created only once, Static variables are like a one-time thing. `One for each activity which extends the class myPreferences`- No it won't

Comment: Will my extend create reflections of my variables if all activities are open at the same time? Also which of two methods do you recommend? I am also open for alternative solutions

Comment: I have added more comments in the answer, also I would create a helper method that creates these preferences for me, or make it static, in your case helpers are better as you are sure there are no leaks of any sort

Comment: Could you please give an example for making a helper?

Comment: Any example, which is the best method please

Comment: Sure give me some time and I will.

Comment: If you could tell me what you were trying to achieve it would be easier for me

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to optimize my application. I am trying to find which method is most correct. Which achieves better performance and is less dangerous for memory leaks. If my method is ok then i am fine. Also if difference between two methods is unoticable then i will leave it as it is. If you have any better  and tested example, i am open to learn new methods

Comment: The best method according to me is keeping it in a local database rather then a preference as that is smarter/easier to maintain, then what you can do as you switch through your activities you can simply get the database connection and get your data from the same, SO no static variables, no memory leaks and no worries if the data is null as it will return a default object in that case! What are your thoughts on the same?

Comment: I dont want to use local database for example 15 preferences. Also is it good idea to read always database for 15 values which are always the same in all activities?

Comment: So you are telling me these value will never change? Like literally never? Also are these primitive types?

Comment: My values are changing only when user is going in settings menu. When user press save in settings i save all settings in shared preferences. If i will leave my code as it is am i ok?

Comment: Yeah you are pretty much okay, It would better if you keep the preferences public read it once and then save them in the static variable for the rest of the time you need it but make sure on setting change you also change the static variable data when your app is still on

Comment: Thank G.hakim. when you said save them in static variable are you mean as my second method?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant

Answer (score 1):

Rather bundling this logic into an `Activity`, I would instead create a separate class that encapsulates the behaviour you want. As an example:

```
class PlayerSettings {

    private static final String KEY_NAME = "com.my.packagename.PLAYER_SETTINGS_NAME";
   //Again for other keys...

    private final SharedPreferences prefs;

    PlayerSettings(SharedPreferences prefs) {
        this.prefs = prefs;
    }

    String name() {
        return prefs.getString(KEY_NAME, "");
    }

    float maxHealth() {
        return prefs.getFloat(KEY_MAX_HEALTH, 0.0f);
    }

    float minHealth() {
        return prefs.getFloat(KEY_MIN_HEALTH, 0.0f);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = PrefenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
final PlayerSettings player = new PlayerSettings(prefs);

player.maxHealth();
player.name();
```

Comment: Isn't it pointless to read always from share preferences when my varaibles are same for all activities. Is it better to create a private static foreach variable? And then to return this when class is called?

Comment: You can cache them/lazily initalise them if you liked, but to be honest the overhead is so small reading from SharedPrefs that I would just leave it as it is in case you decide to make these values dynamic in future

Comment: So you suggest me to leave my code as it is? Right? Also in my tests, i didn't notice any performance when i changed my variables in static.

Comment: Should i leave my code as it is? And looking in future for changing my values in dynamic?

Comment: It's entirely up to you

Comment: You mean that it doesn't make any difference. Right?

Comment: In terms of performance, no - none of these options will differ in terms of performance in any meaningful/real world sense. The solution *I* use would depend entirely on what code is more readable, and more easily re-usable, which is why I would create a separate class for this.

In my own apps, I would supply this via a dependency injection framework (Dagger 2), and inject it into anywhere that needed it (which wouldn't be an Activity. It would probably be a `Presenter` of some sort)